# Problems with element the same class

Tags: jquery

When a value is typed into any of the jam inputs I want to use an onkeyup handler to take the value of only the jam input that generated the event and use it to modify only the Menit input directly below it, not all of them .

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
<hr>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>

$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function hitung_jam() {
var jam = $(this).val();
    var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
    $(this).nextAll(".menit").first().val(waktu_jam);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove `hitung_jam`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function () {
    var jam = $(this).val();
    var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
    $(this).parent().next().find('.menit').val(waktu_jam);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the current input `jam` element's `parent` and then you need to traverse to the next element which is `td` in this case and then look for its children which will be your `merit` 
Try this code:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function hitung_jam() {
var jam = $(this).val();
    var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
    $(this).parent().next().children().val(waktu_jam);
});
```

Check this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/rmc3m2m1/1/

Hope this helps!!